# Astute-class submarine nose module shape

Tags: fluid-mechanics, steel, welding, ships, naval-engineering

[image]

The nose module features a continuous ridge running along it's side. The rest of the hull has the typical "cigar" shape as other sub designs.

(Q1) Does the "ridge" have a proper technical term?

(Q2) What are the merits of this vs a smooth rounded nose?

(Q3) What are the likely motivations for this solution beyond stealth?

(Q4) Are there any implications on the steel fabrication process and detailing?

Comment: You are completely allowed to do further reading.

Comment: 4)Bear in mind that it is not part of the pressure hull. I'm not even sure it is steel.

Comment: @SolarMike Make that "*references for my* further reading"

Comment: @GregLocock Correct and the question relates to the nose as part of the outer hull. I've assumed a steel alloy, however, this is about geometry and construction not so much the choice of material.

Comment: @SolarMike It strikes me that this is a subject on which there may be further reading OP is _not_ allowed to do.

Comment: @SolarMike  The statement could mislead. I've removed it.